# Simplify summation with factorial in denominator

Tags: summation, simplicial-stuff

I don't understand one of the steps in this solution.

**The original problem is:**

$E[X^n] = \frac{2^n}{n+1}$. Find the distributions of X.

**Solution:**

Using the following definition of the moment generating function one can write:

$\psi_X(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{E[X^k]}{k!}t^k= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\frac{2^k}{k+1}}{k!}t^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^kt^k}{(k+1)k!} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2t)^k}{(k+1)!}=$

*the next step is the one I don't get:*

$= \frac{1}{2t} \left( \sum_{k=0}^\infty  \frac{(2t)^k}{k!} -1 \right) = \frac{1}{2t}(e^{2t}-1)$

And I know from a previous exercise that this is the moment generating function for $U(0,2)$, hence $X$~$U(0,2)$

Any hints or ideas to the step I don't get? How would one normally go about to expand/simplify such a sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After letting $j=k+1$, we get 
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2t)^k}{(k+1)!}= \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(2t)^{j-1}}{j!}=\frac{1}{2t}\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{(2t)^{j}}{j!}
=\frac{1}{2t}\left(\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(2t)^{j}}{j!}-1\right) = \frac{1}{2t}(e^{2t}-1)$$
where $e^x=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^j}{j!}$ has been used.

Comment: The clue is thus to make the change of variables: $j = k+1$, which makes the lower limit $k=0$ change to $j=1$.

Comment: Yes!! That's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Remember the Taylor (or simply, power) series of the exponential function:

$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

This series has infinite convergence radius, which means it is true for *any* $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$ . Well, what you have there is just the series for $\;e^{2t}\;$ : just substitute $\;2t=x\;$ in the series... **but** ... I'm sure that $\;1\;$ in the series *must* be  out of it, i.e.: it should be

$$\frac1{2t}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(2t)^n}{n!}-1\right)$$

Comment: I corrected the parenthesis

Comment: @SalamEkshi Yes, you did...and you change the question, and it is *very different* from what you wrote first and to which I answered above.

Comment: Yes, you are correct @DonAntonio, it changes the interpretation of the question.